# stick div element on footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div stick to footer on window scroll. my code is working almost correct but can't figure out whats missing.

```js
function checkOffset() {
  var eTop = $('#footer').offset().top;
  var chatTop = $('#chatArea').offset().top + $('#chat').innerHeight();
  var zero = ($(window).innerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop());
  var posFooter = eTop - zero;
  var posChat = chatTop - zero;
  if (posChat >= posFooter - 2) {
    $('#chatArea').css('bottom', -posFooter);
  } else {
    $('#chatArea').css('bottom', 0);
  }
  console.log(posFooter);
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
  checkOffset();
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 540px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#chatArea {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #007cdc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  ...
  <div id="chatArea"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

This is the fiddle i've done for this case (the height of the wrapper was just for this example).
https://jsfiddle.net/v92qk4tn/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `position:fixed; bottom: 0;` on the footer?

Comment: wont that make the footer always visible in the window? the page will have scroll and dont want the footer to be always in the bottom of window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out how to make this work.

JS function:

```
function checkOffset() {
    var eTop = $('#footer').offset().top;
    var zero = ($(window).innerHeight()+$(window).scrollTop());
    var posFooter = eTop - zero;

    if(posFooter <= 0) {
        $('#chatArea').css('bottom', -posFooter);
    }
    else {
        $('#chatArea').css('bottom', 0);
    }
}
```

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just miss slept an Id name `#chatArea` https://jsfiddle.net/v92qk4tn/2/

Comment: tks for that =) it's almost perfect but when i scroll up the div should stay sticked to the footer until the footer disapears and there's a moment when you see it go to the bottom of the screen. if you could help me with that i would be apreciated =) anyways, tks again.

Comment: @eskimopest you marked this as the correct answer, but your comment makes it sound like this still isn't right. Which is it?

Comment: @henry one of the issues was corrected by Abhishek Pandey. that´s why i marked it as correct. i'm sorry if i should not have marked it. should i remove it? i'm still "discovering" how SO woks... anyway, i came here to post that i solved the problem. =) should i update my question with the correct code?

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying you did something wrong :) I just wasn't sure what had happened. If you solved the code on your own one thing you could do is write an answer (down at the bottom of this page) and then mark it as "accepted" (SO will tell you to uncheck this one first). That way if someone else ever has the same problem and finds this question they can just follow the answer that has the green check mark. But def no harm done either way

Comment: tks =) as i said im "new" here and still figuring this out. i'll do that.